# CakePHP debug set to 0, but it's still debuggin

Tags: php, debugging, cakephp

My cake setup has debug set to 0, but it's still debugging to app/tmp/logs/debug.log. Just to make sure there was no voodoo going on, I even printed out Configure::read('debug') and it spits out 0. Does anyone have any idea why this would be happening? Here is a repeated log result from this debug log:

```
2013-02-15 01:25:41 Notice: Strict (2048): Non-static method App::_loadVendor() should not be called statically in [/var/www/website/htdocs/lib/Cake/Core/App.php, line 614]
Trace:
App::_loadVendor() - CORE/Cake/Core/App.php, line 614
App::import() - CORE/Cake/Core/App.php, line 614
include - APP/View/Helper/AdHelper.php, line 3
App::load() - CORE/Cake/Core/App.php, line 497
spl_autoload_call - [internal], line ??
class_exists - [internal], line ??
HelperCollection::load() - CORE/Cake/View/HelperCollection.php, line 75
View::loadHelpers() - CORE/Cake/View/View.php, line 577
View::render() - CORE/Cake/View/View.php, line 359
Controller::render() - CORE/Cake/Controller/Controller.php, line 898
Dispatcher::_invoke() - CORE/Cake/Routing/Dispatcher.php, line 114
Dispatcher::dispatch() - CORE/Cake/Routing/Dispatcher.php, line 89
[main] - APP/webroot/index.php, line 96
```

Also I am using PHP 5.4, and am running CakePHP 2.3.

Thanks.

Comment: is that the only line in the debug log?

Comment: This is not the only line in the debug log, it's about 1GB in size, and I cleared it about a week ago. All the entries resemble this format, but aren't identical.

Comment: are they all 'strict' errors? Strict (2048):

Comment: Nope, but you are onto something. As soon as I changed my error level E_ALL & ~E_DEPRECATED & ~E_STRICT the strict errors stopped going into the debug log. I still don't understand why the debug log is being used as an error log. I am slowing taking out the errors, so the file isn't getting written to as often.

Comment: my guess, without looking at the cake codebase, is that setting the 'level' to 0 checks for a loosely typed value and evaluates to false, then overriding a false or empty value for that and defaults it to some standard level (presumably E_ALL).

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you are completely (for every controllers & actions) turning off your debugging mode. Try this code in your cake `core.php` file.

```
Configure::write('Error', array(
    'handler' => 'ErrorHandler::handleError',
    'level' => 0,
    'trace' => false
));
```

For more details check [here](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/development/errors.html#error-configuration).

Comment: I replaced my error config with the one that you posted here, but that didn't stop the debug log from filling up. Also, shouldn't the errors go to the error log?

Comment: See answer below - notices go to debug rather than error log by default

Answer (score 0):

If you set debug to 0, any calls to debug() or Debugger::log will write to debug.log (unless you have overwritten the default). Whereas, with debug greater than 0, calls to debug() will display as flash messages in the browser (at the top of the view if called from Model or Controller and in-line if called from View).

You can define what type of errors go into which log in bootstrap.php:

```
App::uses('CakeLog', 'Log');
CakeLog::config('debug', array(
    'engine' => 'FileLog',
    'types' => array('info', 'debug', 'notice'),
    'file' => 'debug',
));
CakeLog::config('error', array(
    'engine' => 'FileLog',
    'types' => array('warning', 'error', 'critical', 'alert', 'emergency'),
    'file' => 'error',
));
```

By default Cake places 'notice' in the types array for the 'debug' CakeLog::config, meaning that notices go into debug.log. Copy 'notice' into the types array for the 'error' config and it should place notices in error.log instead.